# Как с помощью python объединить все файлы json формата в один?

Tags: python, json

У меня более ста файлов json с одинаковой структурой. Нужно их объединить в один json файл. Нагуглил следующий пример, но он выдает ошибку:

```
def do_merge():
    merged = []
    for infile in glob.glob("*.json"):
        with open(infile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infp:
            data = json.load(infp)
            merged.extend(data)
    with open("merged_file.json", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfp:
        json.dump(merged, outfp)
```

Читаю все файлы из одной директории и записываю все в один файл все в той же директории. Ошибка:JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Json на валидность проверил:

```
{
    "id": "b193f0b9d7ad",
    "imp": [{
        "id": "0",
        "instl": 0,
        "tagid": "TAG_ID",
        "secure": 0,
        "exp": 1800,
        "banner": {
            "format": [{
                "w": 300,
                "h": 100
            }, {
                "w": 240,
                "h": 400
            }, {
                "w": 300,
                "h": 600
            }, {
                "w": 300,
                "h": 300
            }, {
                "w": 1920,
                "h": 1080
            }, {
                "w": 300,
                "h": 50
            }, {
                "w": 1024,
                "h": 768
            }, {
                "w": 480,
                "h": 320
            }, {
                "w": 768,
                "h": 1024
            }, {
                "w": 320,
                "h": 250
            }, {
                "w": 300,
                "h": 250
            }, {
                "w": 160,
                "h": 600
            }, {
                "w": 320,
                "h": 850
            }, {
                "w": 720,
                "h": 90
            }, {
                "w": 320,
                "h": 480
            }, {
                "w": 640,
                "h": 360
            }, {
                "w": 640,
                "h": 480
            }, {
                "w": 1280,
                "h": 720
            }, {
                "w": 720,
                "h": 1080
            }, {
                "w": 336,
                "h": 280
            }, {
                "w": 320,
                "h": 100
            }, {
                "w": 728,
                "h": 90
            }, {
                "w": 250,
                "h": 250
            }, {
                "w": 970,
                "h": 250
            }, {
                "w": 970,
                "h": 90
            }, {
                "w": 320,
                "h": 50
            }, {
                "w": 360,
                "h": 640
            }, {
                "w": 720,
                "h": 1280
            }],
            "pos": 0
        },
        "floor": 0.55,
        "bid": "USD"
    }],
    "user": {
        "id": "6a0c504"
    },
    "at": 2
}
```

Подскажите как сделать правильно. Благодарю

Comment: Поставьте внутри цикла `for` печать имени файла `print(infile)` и проверьте ещё раз содержимое файла, на котором код падает.

Comment: Согласен. У меня все загрузилось.

Comment: И ещё проверьте, что в вашем коде точно используется `json.load(infp)`, а не `json.loads(infp)` с буквой `s` в конце, судя по ошибке очень похоже на то.

Comment: CrazyElf, после merged.extend(data) поставил print, выводит имена всех файлов. Но в конце опять та же ошибка. При том, что закомментировал запись в файл. JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last) 3
    291     kwarg; otherwise ``JSONDecoder`` is used.
    292     """
--> 293     return loads(fp.read(),
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int.

Comment: CrazyElf, в коде load без с. Но в Traceback ошибке (return loads(fp.read()) почему-то loads.

Comment: Поставьте `print` сразу после `for` перед `with open`, имя файла, которое напечатает перед ошибкой надо будет проверить. Сейчас вы печатаете только успешно обработанные файлы и не знаете, в каком файле ошибка.

Comment: А, ну то, что в трейсе - это нормально, внутри себя `json.load(infp)` на самом деле делает `json.loads(infp.read())` и это всё правильно.

Comment: CrazyElf, печатает все файла, а потом та же ошибка. Ошибка указывает на строку data = json.load(infp). Проблема может быть в библиотеке?

Comment: Вот последнее имя файла, которое печатает перед ошибкой - этот файл проблемный. Или выложите его куда-то или сами ещё раз посмотрите, и хорошо бы в редакторе, который коды символов показывает, что-то с этим файлом не то. Может кодировка не та, может какой-то символ не тот там затесался в начало.

Comment: И ещё. Это не имеет отношения к ошибке, но скорее всего вам нужно использовать не `merged.extend(data)`, а `merged.append(data)`, сейчас у вас в список только ключи словарей попадают, а не словари целиком.

Comment: CrazyElf, заменил на merged.append(data) и изменил директорию файла для записи результата. Ошибки нет, записалось корректно. Спасибо. Ошибка наверное была в том, что при итерации читались все файлы из директории, в том числе файл, в который шла запись

Comment: *читались все файлы из директории, в том числе файл, в который шла запись* - да, наверняка в этом дело было, и как я не сообразил, что есть такая возможность )